# Limit between community and doing others people job

Tags: discussion

Is there any limit between helping as a community member and doing someone else's job? 
From time to time i come across some users who tends to think this is a free consultation page and demand instead of asking for help/clarification. Is there any known limit? 
Some idiomatic barriers might apply in some cases, like the missuses  of some words, but in some questions is clear that the spirit of a community is not even close to be present.
Ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some examples to be clear ? What kind of questions do you mean exactly ?

Comment: This is clear, i think most of the guys here have been in that situation. One is this question from today: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29029/count-of-viewable-products-in-a-category/29030#29030
, i will add some more when i get to see them again. For example this user http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/7914/ajay-kulkarni has made 5 questions about a STL file which is pretty much an entire project. I understand the place need questions to run, but i think at some point it might be an abuse.

Comment: I think the question about products count is a critical question as there is no pre-defined Magento code for gathering viewable products. I've tested many days and used different codes. I think you need to take a more deep look at that question, still no one provide any proper solution on this. Of course your answer was one of the ways I've tested but it calculates more products than actual ones. I don't think I've done any abuse on this, just a simple question about gathering viewable products.

Comment: And of course this type of question could be super useful to whoever search for example "count of viewable products in Magento". I think it could be very useful.

Comment: The words you are using are closer to a demand than to a question.  I *really* think manner count.

Comment: I really don't want anyone think like this about my questions/answers because I didn't want to do it. The question was really importnant question I think and I didn't find anything wrong with it. Can you please advice me how to change my question so that it fits to the community ?

Comment: A please and thank you is enough for me.

Comment: I think we should avoid such words in the community : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions ... and this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts ... But I agree with you anyway.

Comment: In fact, the articles you posted are about questions. I not sure they apply for answers as well.

Comment: I understand, we need to be nice in the comments, no I understand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer the questions you feel like answering. If someone seems imperative in their initial tone or in their followup, first consider if it's a *language* issue (ofttimes it is).

If someone is obnoxious to you, ignore them if you like. As long as your answer satisfies the original question others can upvote and benefit can be derived from the larger audience.